# Calling a pre-defined Access query using ODBC in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net

I am using c# and `OdbcConnection` to connect to an Access database. Inside the database there is a pre-defined query that I want to run (like a stored proc in Sql Server). This used to be dead easy with the old COM-based ADO but it doesn't seem to work in ADO.net

```
OdbcConnection conn = AccessConnect.Connect();
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"MyAccessQuery;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Is there a way round it or am I going to have to duplicate my Access query in C# code?

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = @"select * from MyAccessQuery;";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` doesn't work?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the OleConnection and OleDataAdapter?

Comment: No both give invalid sql error

Comment: Yeah that works copied the Odbc stuff from somewhere I should have used OleDb instead.

Comment: Is your saved query in Access a straightforward SELECT query with no parameters?

Comment: Yes but it calls a vba function which is nothing to do with the problem I raised but stops me using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Access ODBC (and OLEDB) interfaces expose saved queries in Access as either Views or Stored Procedures. How they are exposed determines the way they can be used by an external application.

Saved SELECT queries in Access that *do not* use PARAMETERS are exposed as Views, so they can be used like a table, e.g.

```cs
string sql = "SELECT * FROM mySavedSelectQuery WHERE id <= 3";
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    using (var da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Console.WriteLine("DataTable contains {0} row(s)", dt.Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Other types of saved queries in Access are exposed as Stored Procedures, so they need to be called using the ODBC `{CALL ...}` syntax, like so:

```cs
string sql = "{CALL mySavedParameterQuery (?)}";
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // set parameter values (if any) in the order that they appear 
    //     in the PARAMETERS list of the saved query
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int).Value = 3;
    using (var da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Console.WriteLine("DataTable contains {0} row(s)", dt.Rows.Count);
    }
}
```

Note that in both of the above cases, as with any query against an Access database from an external application (C#, VB.NET, Java, etc.), there are some restrictions. For example, some Access built-in functions may not be available, and saved Access queries that call user-defined functions (written in VBA) will not work from a direct ODBC or OLEDB connection.